# unifying tags pyqt4 and pyqt

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I tried to do this myself today, but got stopped but some more experienced user. For questions about PyQt two tags are defined: `pyqt` and `pyqt4`. There are no `pyqt3` questions, so I would like to suggest to unify those two tags into one: `pyqt`. No people use either one or another or both.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when it comes to tags with versions, you should use:

- [pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt) for posts that are version-generic
- [pyqt4](/questions/tagged/pyqt4) for posts that only apply to version 4, and don't make sense for other versions

If somebody has a question about something that's version 3-specific, they should create the [pyqt3](/questions/tagged/pyqt3) tag; it looks like nobody has had such a question yet (or they didn't tag it correctly)